# Getting error with Appium automation

Tags: java, android, appium

Getting the error as below mentioned:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Appium\AndroidSDKs\platforms\android-23\android.jar;D:\Appium\AndroidSDKs\platforms\android-23\data\res;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\classes\androidTest\debug;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\gson-2.3.1.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\httpmime-4.4.1.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\guava-18.0.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\commons-exec-1.3.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\httpcore-4.4.1.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\selenium-java-2.47.1.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\23.1.1\res;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\23.1.1\jars\classes.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7\23.1.1\jars\classes.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7\23.1.1\res;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.1.1\jars\libs\internal_impl-23.1.1.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.1.1\res;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.1.1\jars\classes.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\commons-codec-1.10.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\junit-4.12.jar;D:\Appium\AndroidSDKs\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\23.1.1\support-annotations-23.1.1.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\jars\classes.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\httpclient-4.4.1.jar;D:\Appium\MobileAutomation\MyApplication\lib\java-client-3.2.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.example.bhaskarac.myapplication.Amazan

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:251)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:228)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:63)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:36)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:167)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:69)
at com.example.bhaskarac.myapplication.Amazan.main(Amazan.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Process finished with `exit code 1`.

My program is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
public class Amazan {
    private static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.out.println(classpathRoot);
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/Amazon/");
        File app = new File(appDir, "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping.apk");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Comment: While exception stacktrace and source code are fine, it would be also nice if you could provide some background info about what you are trying to do, what is the expected behaviour, etc....

Comment: I am new to appium automation. Installed the android studio and trying to run the above mentioned sample code after launching the appium.

Comment: make sure ur appium runs on the same port 4444 u specified

Comment: Appium running on 4444 port only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
public class amazon {
    private static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users**.....your app full path\**com.amazon.mShop.android-5.2.0-APK4Fun.com.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.amazon.mShop.android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Make sure the port no u use in the program is same as the one used to start appium

Comment: I opted the Java project as module and later changed the run -> settings. Finally working fine. Thanks!