# Error "SuchFieldError: INSTANCE" but not duplicated Jar detected (Appium/Android Studio/IntelliJ)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, appium

I got an error when running below simple code but I don't know how to solve?
I just check in eclipse and It runs well. However, in IntelliJ I got error

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=61118 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/duyetmai/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar:/Users/duyetmai/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/data/res:/Users/duyetmai/IdeaProjects/Testing_duyetmai/out/production/Testing_duyetmai:/Users/duyetmai/Downloads/java-client-5.0.0-BETA6.jar:/Users/duyetmai/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2 com.appium.android.LaunchApp
>   **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
>       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)**
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:250)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.(ApacheHttpClient.java:227)
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:111)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:73)
>       at com.appium.android.LaunchApp.main(LaunchApp.java:24)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:143)

Process finished with exit code 1

```
package com.appium.android;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by aa on 4/9/17.
 */
public class LaunchApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");

        capabilities.setCapability("app", "\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\TrainingVideo\\Mobiletest\\zalo_x86.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.zing.zalo");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".ui.ZaloLauncherActivity");
        try {
            URL URLaddress = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
            AndroidDriver driverxx = new AndroidDriver(URLaddress, capabilities);
        } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

I did some research and found that with this error, perhaps i used duplicated JAR files . However, i checked and saw that I just use three external libraries.
java-client-5.0.0-BETA6.jar
selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar
Android API 25 Platform

So what is the problem?
My IDE is intelliJ and i'm runing on MAC OS with Appium v1.6.4 and emulated Android 7. (Nexus 5)

```
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

Comment: Please present your question. There is no **?** anywhere to be seen.

Comment: Hi, i added ? in my question.

Comment: this guy had same problem with me however i don't understand how he solve this issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363268/getting-error-with-appium-automation
He just say "I opted the Java project as module and later changed the run -> settings. Finally working fine. Thanks! – bhaskar kumar Feb 16 '16 at 5:56"

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that i shouldn't include Android API 25 Platform